# How to optimize search with list dir and path walk?

Tags: python, search, os.path, listdir

Python 2.7.5 Win/Mac.

I'm trying to find the best way to search files (over 10000) on multiple storages (about 128Tio). These files have specific extensions and I can ignore some folders.

Here is my first function with `os.listdir` and recursion :

```
count = 0
def SearchFiles1(path):
    global count
    pathList = os.listdir(path)
    for i in pathList:
        subPath = path+os.path.sep+i
        if os.path.isfile(subPath) == True :
            fileName = os.path.basename(subPath)
            extension = fileName[fileName.rfind("."):]
            if ".ext1" in extension or ".ext2" in extension or ".ext3" in extension:
                count += 1
                #do stuff . . .
        else :
            if os.path.isdir(subPath) == True:
                if not "UselessFolder1" in subPath and not "UselessFolder1" in subPath:
                    SearchFiles1(subPath)
```

It works, but i think it could be better (faster and proper) or am I wrong?

So I tried `os.path.walk`:

```
def SearchFiles2(path):
    count = 0
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for i in dirpath:
            if not "UselessFolder1" in i and not "UselessFolder1" in i:
                for y in files:
                    fileName = os.path.basename(y)
                    extension = fileName[fileName.rfind("."):]
                    if ".ext2" in extension or ".ext2" in extension or ".ext3" in extension:
                        count += 1
                        # do stuff . . .
    return count
```

"count" is wrong and a way slower. And I think I don't really understand how `path.walk` works.

My question is: what can I do to optimize this research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is reasonable except that you could use `os.path.splitext`. In the second solution, its incorrect because you revisit the files list for each subdir instead of just processing it once. With `os.path.walk` the trick is that directories removed from `subdirs` are not part of the next round of enumerations.

```
def SearchFiles2(path):
    useless_dirs = set(("UselessFolder1", "UselessFolder2"))
    useless_files = set((".ext1", ".ext2"))
    count = 0
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        # remove unwanted subdirs from future enumeration
        for name in set(subdirs) & useless_dir:
            subdirs.remove(name)
        # list of interesting files
        myfiles = [os.path.join(dirpath, name) for name in files
            if os.path.splitext(name)[1] not in useless_files]
        count += len(myfiles)
        for filepath in myfiles:
            # example shows file stats
            print(filepath, os.stat(filepath)
    return count
```

Enumerating the file system of a single storage unit can only go so fast. The best way to speed this up is to run the enumeration of different storage units in different threads.

Comment: Thanks to your example i improved the 1st solution (os.path.splitext an d compare string to tuple content). It's a little bit faster and we can easy add more rules (file ext / ignore subdir).

Comment: For the 2nd solution i didn't manage to make it work. First i guess it's 'useless_dirs' in line 7 but i got the error : 'ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list'. 
I added "print name" and saw it try to remove useless_dirs[x] from subdirs even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Syrius My bad... I used `and` when I should have used `&`.

Comment: Now it works fine !
One last thing. How get the full path of the file ?
I replaced :
`myfiles = [name for name in files
            if os.path.splitext(name)[1] not in useless_files]
        count += len(myfiles)`
by
`for f in [name for name in files if os.path.splitext(name)[1] in target_files]:
            count += 1
            # do stuff . . .`
The goal is not just to count but also do copy, get size or date etc. But f give only filename.

Comment: @Syrius I've updated the example to create a file path you can use for other operations.

Answer (score 0):

So after tests and discussion with tdelaney I optimized both solutions as follow:

```
import os

count = 0
target_files = set((".ext1", ".ext2", ".ext3")) # etc
useless_dirs = set(("UselessFolder2", "UselessFolder2")) # etc
# it could be target_dirs, just change `in` with `not in` when compared.

def SearchFiles1(path):
    global count
    pathList = os.listdir(path)
    for content in pathList:
        fullPath = os.path.join(path,content)
        if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
            if os.path.splitext(fullPath)[1] in target_files:
                count += 1
                #do stuff with 'fullPath' . . .
        else :
            if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
                if fullPath not in useless_dirs:
                    SearchFiles1(fullPath)

def SearchFiles2(path):
    count = 0
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in set(subdirs) & useless_dirs:
            subdirs.remove(name)
        for filename in [name for name in files if os.path.splitext(name)[1] in target_files]:
            count += 1
            fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            #do stuff with 'fullPath' . . .
    return count
```

It works fine on Mac/PC v2.7.5

About speed it's totally even.